# Matching a full repeating pattern

Tags: regex, repeat

I can't seem to figure out this regex
https://regex101.com/r/cQ9nK8/38

These should match

- January.313
- January
- January.31.Feb.6
- GMI3.0.N.1
- January.31.Feb.6.March.7

This should not match

- April.May

As you can see they match individually but not as a whole, I though this would work but it doesn't

```
(?:[[:alnum:]]+(?:\.\d+)*)*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a repeating pattern:

- First match `[[:alpha:]]` followed by optional `[[:alnum:]]` (if the first of 2 parts separated by a dot should not start with a digit)

  This would match `January`
- Followed by an optional part that matches digit

  That will match `January.313`
- Optionally repeat a dot followed by the same pattern

  That will match the last 3 examples.

Pattern

```
^[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*(?:\.[[:digit:]]+(?:\.[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*\.[[:digit:]]+)*)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1P1nnD/1)

A version without the POSIX notation could be

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*\.[0-9]+)*)?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*` Match a char a-zA-Z optionally followed by a-zA-Z and digits
- `(?:` non capture group

  - `\.[0-9]+` Match a `.` and 1+ digits
  - `(?:\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*\.[0-9]+)*` Optionally repeat matching `.` a char a-zA-Z optionally followed by a-zA-Z and digits, a dot and digits
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tI6nGX/1)

Comment: @JvdV The first one doesn't but it is quite verbose

Comment: Thanks, this is my final regex

'^[\w\d]*(?:\.[\d]+(?:\.[\w]*\.[\d]+)*)?$'

after handling other corner cases with '_' and not matching on this

- Aptil.7.May

Comment: Note that `\w` also matches `\d`

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt:

```
^((?:^|\.)[A-Z][A-Z\d]*(?:$|\.\d+))(?1)*$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cQ9nK8/39)

---

- `^` - Start string ancor.
- `(` - Open 1st capture group/pattern.

  - `(?:` - Open non-capture group.

    - `^|\.` - Start string or literal dot.
    - `)` - Close non capture group.
  - `[A-Z][A-Z\d]*` - A single letter followed by zero or more letters or digits.
  - `(?:` - Open non-capture group.

    - `$|\.` - End string or literal dot.
    - `)` - Close non capture group.
      `)` - Close 1st capture group/pattern.
- `(?1)*` - Repeat the capture group/pattern zero or more times.
- `$` - End string ancor.

---

I've use case insensitive matching btw.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is also helpful but my final  implementation is very close to @The-fourth-bird